# Why does my "print letter with delay" script print all at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm attempting to make a script that prints letter by letter with a small time gap in between each letter. But, instead of printing each letter, it just waits for the combinded time of each letter then prints the entire string.

```
import time
def tyPrint(thingToPrint):
    for letter in thingToPrint:
        print(letter, end="")
        time.sleep(.02)
tyPrint("ow my bones")
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You must `flush` if you don't print out a newline (read the docs for `print`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
import sys
def tyPrint(thingToPrint):
    for letter in thingToPrint:
        print(letter, end="")
        time.sleep(.02)
        sys.stdout.flush()
tyPrint("ow my bones")
```